# Is there an API I can get my total amount of reputation and badges from?

Tags: support, api

I have already seen the flair™ image I can embed on my website. However, I think it's small and I don't really like the design.

I would like to retrieve my overall reputation and badges as seen in the flair™ and display it with a style I make on my own.

I already found http://api.stackexchange.com/, but I couldn't find anything related to an amount of rep.

Is there an free API for that? If yes, what query do I have to call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [the API](http://api.stackexchange.com/) for this. The documentation is good.

In your case you'd use [`/users/{id}/associated`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users) (or `/me/associated`), this will return badge counts and reputation for all sites you are on. You can reconstruct the flair info this way.

The `items` array in the returned object will have an item for each site that looks like:

```
    {
      "badge_counts": {
        "bronze": 96,
        "silver": 52,
        "gold": 5
      },
      "question_count": 53,
      "answer_count": 868,
      "last_access_date": 1494089678,
      "creation_date": 1297699014,
      "account_id": 305991,
      "reputation": 25130,
      "user_id": 616460,
      "site_url": "http://stackoverflow.com",
      "site_name": "Stack Overflow"
    },
```

For your usage you'll probably want to set the `pagesize` to its max of 100 and don't forget to honor the `has_more` parameter to support > 100 accounts. See [paging](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging).

For the profile image it's site specific, so you'll have to use [`/users/{id}`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids) (or `/me`) with the desired `site` parameter to get the URL of the avatar.

For details on specific sites you can use a lot of different things, just look under the **Users** section of http://api.stackexchange.com/docs. Each function is described there and the returned objects are described in every doc page, you'll be able to find whatever you need.

Note that there is a quota on the API. If possible you probably want to do API queries server-side on periodic intervals (or on page loads but cache the data with an expiration time), and serve cached results to clients instead of doing client-side API queries in JavaScript on every page load. Also, it's a polite thing to do!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This will definitely improve my website.